# Angular multi-column sort using $filter and predicate function array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-filters

I need to order an array using the angular `$filter('orderBy')` function, but need to specify three predicate callbacks, and the sort order needs to be ASC, DESC, ASC.

I know that there are many ways to solve the problem of multi-column sort, but my question is specifically about using Angular's orderBy filter to do it.

The examples that I provide are not the actual data, but rather just a simplified model so that it is easier to explain.

I'm aware that you can use simple property names to handle it like this:

```
$scope.arr = $filter('orderBy')($scope.arr, ['+year', '-month', '+payment']);
```

However, my orderBy code looks like this:

```
$scope.arr = $filter('orderBy')($scope.arr, [
      function(row) {
          //complicated logic here...for demo just return the raw property  
          return row.year;
      },
      function(row) {
          //complicated logic here...for demo just return the raw property
          return row.month;
      },
      function(row) {
          //complicated logic here...for demo just return the raw property
          return row.payment;
      }
    ], true);
  }
```

With my array of functions method, I cannot seem to find a way to provide ASC, DESC, ASC sorting order. I can use the third argument to flip the whole array (`$filter('orderBy')($scope.arr,[...], true)`), but that's not what I want.

I've tried forming the array like this, but that didn't work either:

```
['+', function(row){return row.year;}, '-', function(row){return row.month}, '+', function(row){return row.payment;}]
```

I'm out of ideas. Is there any way to use the predicate function callbacks and still get the per-property specified direction sorting?

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter) {
  var id = 0;
  var arr = [];
  //generate some dummy data
  for (var year = 2000; year < 2010; year++) {

    for (var month = 3; month > 0; month--) {
      for (var payment = 100; payment < 300; payment = payment + 50) {
        var row = {
          id: id++,
          year: year,
          month: '0' + month,
          payment: payment
        };
        arr.push(row);
      }
    }
  }
  $scope.arr = arr;

  $scope.order = function() {

      $scope.arr = $filter('orderBy')($scope.arr, [
        function(row) {
          return row.year;
        },
        function(row) {
          return row.month;
        },
        function(row) {
          return row.payment;
        }
      ], true);
    }
    //sort the array right away
  $scope.order();

});
```

```css
th {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      text-align: center;
    }
    td {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Payment</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in arr">
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
        <td>{{row.year}}</td>
        <td>{{row.month}}</td>
        <td>{{row.payment}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like this would be simpler with a custom filter and an object map that stores filter preferences

Comment: Yeah, it might be simpler. But angular is so close to providing this, I was hoping that I just missed something.

Comment: Without knowing more about what your `complicated logic` even does not much we can offer

Comment: @charlietfl, I'm not sure why knowing my complicated logic would matter for this question. When it comes down to it, complicated logic returns a primitive value (number, string, bool, etc...) that angular uses to sort by. My question is: When using an array of function predicates, how do I tell angular to reverse the order of one of the functions, like is provided when giving string property name predicates like ['+year','-month','+payment']'.

Comment: Perhaps you can make that array a variable and simply change the array assigned to the variable. [Something like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/jUhyrWtxj3RVc7xlAWL0?p=preview) might help

Comment: A demo of what you are trying to do might help also

Comment: I know that there are many ways to solve the ordering problem, but my question is specifically focused on how to do it using Angular's orderBy  filter.

Comment: It's just not clear enough to me where your problem really is. Hence a demo would be helpful

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with demo. It is pretty much the same as my snippet in my question, but I added a few more comments to hopefully explain it better. https://jsfiddle.net/oujtwscL/1/

Comment: So the `orderUsingPropertyNames` seems to work well. Not sure what actual functionality needs to change to need to use functions? Just seems more complicated than using a custom filter or only one function

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
function(row) {
      //complicated logic here...for demo just return the raw property  
      return row.year;
  },
  function(row) {
      //complicated logic here...for demo just return the raw property
      return -1*row.month;
  },
  function(row) {
      //complicated logic here...for demo just return the raw property
      return row.payment;
  }
```

Comment: This would only work when the values are numeric. What about string columns?

Comment: Can we not return the string itself? return 'year'; return '-month'; return  'payment'